# Border style of a nested list

Tags: css

In my HTML doc I have a nested list with style:

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:3px;
}

li li {
    list-style:none;

}


<ul>
  <li>something
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>there</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With my current CSS rule borders looks like this:

[image]

I want them to look like this, but without inserting `<span>` tags:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks you're going to need a `span` tag. I tried it a few ways to no avail...

Comment: add `width:40px` or something like that

Comment: @jcho360 , did you mean `height:40px`? I think that will work!

Comment: Ah wait. By adjusting the height/width though it will still adjust all of them. If you just want something to be a small border around the text and hello/there to be full-width it seems you'll still need to use a span - but if you don't mind setting the width/heights explicitly: http://jsfiddle.net/KeXDB/2/

Comment: Yea, just tried, heigh/width does not work if I have more items... I get this goofiness: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16876271/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-16%20at%2012.13.45%20PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
li {
    clear: both;
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:3px;
}
li ul{
    float: left;
}


<ul>
  <li>something
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>there</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>something
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>there</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The result:

[image]